# How to show video by entering link from TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

The context is we have a `TextFormField` and `ElevatedButton`. I entered the URL of the video (usually format mp4) and pressed Button. Bellow them will show videos are scraped from this URL. I think I should use the package video_player. However, in the example code, it required an initial URL on `initState` (or onInit if using the `GetX` package). How to make the URL dynamic and only show after entering the URL?

```
class CyberDropController extends GetxController with StateMixin<List> {
  final dataCyberDrop = DataCyberDrop();
  late VideoPlayerController videoController;
  var url = ''.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    playVideo(url.value);
    change(null, status: RxStatus.empty());
  }

  Future<void> playVideo(String url) async {
    videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
    await videoController.initialize();
    await videoController.setLooping(true);
    await videoController.play();
    update();
  }



  void fetch({String? link}) async {
    change(null, status: RxStatus.loading());
    try {
      var data = await dataCyberDrop.scraperCyberDrop(link: link);
      change(data, status: RxStatus.success());
    } catch (e) {
      change(null, status: RxStatus.error(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

Views:

```
controller.obx(
                (state) => Column(
                  children: state!
                      .map(
                        (e) => e!.toString().contains('.mp4')
                            ? AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: controller
                                    .videoController.value.aspectRatio,
                                child: VideoPlayer(controller.videoController),
                              )
                            : Image.network(e),
                      )
                      .toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

since you said that you're working with `TextFormField`, you can use the `onChanged` property to execute your methods just after you set the URL:

```
TextFormField(
onChanged: (urlValue) async{ 
 if(/* recommended to set a condition on URL where it shouldn't execute anything*/) {
  return;
  }

  await controller.playVideo(urlValue);
  }
 )
```